# Laravel 10 Auth::user() - Attempt to read property on null

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware, roles

All i am trying to do is make a middleware where only user with `role_id = 1` can access the dashboard.

Now keep in mind i didn't use `laravel/breeze`, instead i used `laravel/ui auth`

Here is my checkRole middleware:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
{
    if(Auth::user()->role_id != 1)
    {
        return redirect()->route("welcomepage");
    } 

    return $next($request);

}
```

Here is the middleware in `web.php` :

```
Route::middleware(["checkRole"])->group(function() {
    Auth::routes(["register" => false, "reset" => false]);
    //I use these parameters because i don't want these routes
});
```

I have used the same middleware before with `laravel/breeze` and had no problem but now with `laravel/ui auth` i get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While i was typing the question i randomly came with the solution. `laravel/ui auth` in the `HomeController.php` in the constructor method are the middlewares listed

This is how it looks now:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('checkRole'); //just added it
}
```

And in `web.php` i just removed the middleware and have only:

```
Auth::routes(["register" => false, "reset" => false]);
```

The middleware method stays the same.

Comment: It is not recommended to use `$this->middleware` inside a controller, because it is code not defined on the route itself, so you need to go to the controller to see if there is any middleware applied, that is called "obfuscation", so eventhough this works, it is not a recommended solution... did you define the middleware in the `App/Http/Kernel.php` file?

Comment: Yes i did define it in the `App/Http/Kernel.php`

Answer (score 0):

Add to middleware validation if user is guest